# Can a database format/schema be copyrighted separately from the data?

Tags: copyright, data

I came across a map tile format which requires attribution for use, regardless of the license of the data it contains.  The format specifies how and what map features (roads, water, etc) should be included, but that's basically all it does.

The [website](https://openmaptiles.org/schema/) for the format says the following:

> The vector tile schema describes how the vector data is organized into
>   different thematic layers and which attribute and values each layer
>   contains. This is useful for writing a map style and allows for
>   alternative implementations of a schema.
>
> The OpenMapTiles schema is open (CC-BY) and you are free to use,
>   extend or build upon the existing implementation (BSD license). **Please
>   reference OpenMapTiles if you build upon the schema.**

It seems they're requiring I give them credit for rearranging my data according to their "rules".  Does this requirement have any legal force, since it doesn't cover the actual information stored with the format?

Answer (score 1):

### Yes (to both questions)

The schema is analogous to a cooking recipe. The list of ingredients (the data) is not copyright because it’s a list of facts but the method (schema) is subject to copyright.

Of course, executing a cooking recipe doesn’t breach copyright because you don’t actually copy the recipe - you follow it. However, implementing a database with a given schema necessarily involves copying that schema or creating a derivative work from it. You can only do this with the copyright holder’s permission which means complying with their licence.

Comment: Methods are not copyrightable either (though possibly patentable). In contrast, the *description* of a method may qualify as a copyright-protectable creative work. I am dubious of the claim that a data format itself would be afforded copyright protection. Copyright laws sometimes even encourage the use of existing formats/interfaces for the purpose of interoperability, in which case any license would be irrelevant.

Comment: "Implementing a database with a given schema necessarily involves copying .... or creating a derivative work from it." - How so? This seems like following a recipe. "Create a table named T1 with 5 columns, where the first column is named C1, the second column is named C2, etc."